# how to use hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to use a hash to store the users. I have this code, and it's working, but it's not the way I want it:

```
@user_hash = Hash.new
@user_hash = User.all(:all)

user = Hash.new
user = @user_hash.select { |item| item["user_id"] == '001' }

puts user[0].name
```

How can I use something like `user.name` insted `user[0].name` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to initialise your Hashes before you use them - both calls to `Hash.new` are unnecessary here.

Second, your only problem is that you're using the `select` method. Quoting from the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select):

> Returns a new hash consisting of entries for which the block returns true.

That's not what you want. You want to use `detect`:
Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false.

`user = @user_hash.detect { |item| item["user_id"] == '001' }` should work

Answer (score 1):

To create a hash you should use the following syntax:

`@user_hash = Hash[User.find(:all).collect{|u| [u.user_id, u]}]`

Then you can do something like:

`puts user["001"].name`

Answer (score 0):

`user = Hash.new` is a waste of time as you are overwriting it with the result of the following `select`.

and `select` returns an array of hashes that pass your test.

You want `.find` or its synonym `.detect` instead of `.select`.